# What makes RecordIO attractive

Tags: record, file-format

I have been reading about RecordIO [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16813030) and [there](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=19623710) and checking different implementations on github [here](https://github.com/grailbio/base/tree/master/recordio), and [there](https://github.com/eclesh/recordio). 
I'm simply trying to wrap my head around the pros of such a file format.

The pros I see are the following:

1. Block compression. It will be faster if you need to read only a few records because less to decompress.
2. Because of the somehow indexed structure you could lookup a specific record in acceptable time (assuming keys are sorted). This can be useful to quickly locate a record in an adhoc fashion.
3. I can also imagine that with such a file format you can have finer sharding strategies. Instead of sharding per file you can shard per block.

But I fail to see how such a file format is faster for reading over some plain protobuf with compression.

Essentially I fail to see a big pro in this format.